# Listener not working correctly within Swing application

Tags: java, swing, scanning

I have the following sample class which connects to twain.dll driver using the uk.co.mmscomputing.device.scanner.Scanner class to scan a page:

```
public class ScannerManager implements ScannerListener{

       static ScannerManager app;  

       Scanner scanner;
       String fileName;

       public ScannerManager() throws ScannerIOException{

        scanner=Scanner.getDevice();
        scanner.addListener(this);    
        scanner.acquire();
       }



    public void update(ScannerIOMetadata.Type type, ScannerIOMetadata metadata){

        if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.ACQUIRED)){

          BufferedImage image=metadata.getImage();
          System.out.println("ACQUIRED!");
            String file = UIMessages.showInputMessage("Enter file name");
          try{
            ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File(Constants.getPathBusta()  + File.separatorChar + file));
            fileName = Constants.getPathBusta()  + File.separatorChar + file;

          }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.NEGOTIATE)){

          ScannerDevice device=metadata.getDevice();
          try{
            device.setShowUserInterface(true);
            device.setShowProgressBar(true);
            device.setResolution(100);
          }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
          }
        }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.STATECHANGE)){

          System.err.println(metadata.getStateStr());
          if(metadata.isFinished()){
            System.exit(0);
          }
        }else if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.EXCEPTION)){

          metadata.getException().printStackTrace();
        }
      }

      public static void main(String[] argv){
        try{
          app=new ScannerManager( );
        }catch(Exception e){
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }

}
```

It works perfectly when run through the main method, however I need it to be invoked from a **Swing jButton** click event:
Suprisingly, it does not work the same:

```
buttonAcquire.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                try {

                    ScannerManager scanner = new ScannerManager();

                } catch (ScannerIOException e1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                    defaultCursor();
                }

            }
});
```

The condition:

```
  if(type.equals(ScannerIOMetadata.ACQUIRED))
```

is never met so it seems that events are not being intercepted correctly when executing from a Swing Thread. Can you give me any hint ? I'm really puzzled by it and I don't know what could be the problem.....

Comment: to start with reading oracle tutorial - Concurency in Swing, part event dispatch thread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making the Swing class itself listening to the ScannerListener event. In other words move the code into the Swing UI part and see if it works.